# How to deal with NaN or inf in OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders

Tags: android, iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, gpgpu

This is based on the question: [Best way to detect NaN's in OpenGL shaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446888/best-way-to-detect-nans-in-opengl-shaders)
Standard GLSL defines isnan() and isinf() functions for detection. OpenGL ES 2.0 shading language doesn't. How can I deal with NaNs and Infs nevertheless?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for NaN via a condition that will only be true for NaN:

```
bool isNan(float val)
{
  return (val <= 0.0 || 0.0 <= val) ? false : true;
}
```

`isinf` is a bit more difficult. There is no mechanism to convert the float into its integer representation and play with the bits. So you'll have to compare it against a suitably large number.

Comment: Thanks! Why isn't this in the official spec? Are there platforms where this isn't working?

Comment: @RafaelSpring There might be. Notoriously, most GPU hardware takes shortcuts w.r.t. floats that result in __non-__ IEEE 754 compliant floats. As such, I doubt your required behavior is guaranteed. So as Nicol suggests, your best bet is probably to have a good idea of the minimum and maximum value you would expect during normal operations, and check that your value is in that range. Otherwise, it's probably either `Inf` or `NaN`.

Comment: @SchighSchagh Even the results of comparison operators may not be guaranteed where NaNs are involved if the compiler and/or GPU is not IEEE-754 compliant. I've experienced situations where a lax compiler produces code for `<` which always evaluates to true if either argument is NaN. The safest approach is to prevent NaNs from ever being generated in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem for WebGL. Answer of Nicol Bolas works good for most GPUs but does not for some nVidias. This version works good for all GPUs I had an opportunity to try:

```
bool isNan( float val )
{
  return ( val < 0.0 || 0.0 < val || val == 0.0 ) ? false : true;
  // important: some nVidias failed to cope with version below.
  // Probably wrong optimization.
  /*return ( val <= 0.0 || 0.0 <= val ) ? false : true;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, so not sure this will work (due to optimizations), but it should work, both for Inf and -Inf.

```
  bool isinf(float val) {
    return (val != 0.0 && val * 2.0 == val) ? true : false;
  }
```