# GLSL If always returns true

Tags: glsl, shader

I have `float brightness` with a dot production of 2 vectors in it. `brightness` should be positive most of the time, but to make sure I use `max(brightness, 0.0)`. When I try to use `brightness` in my lighting system nothing shows on display. I tried to debug this with if-statement, but it seems it returns always true or something. So `if(brightness > 99999)` and `if(brightness < 99999)` or `if(brightness == 12345)` all discards the pixel. I am using GLSL version 430 core.

```
float brightness = dot(vector1, vector2);
brightness = max(brightness, 0.0);

if(brightness < -999) {

    discard;

}
```

So in this example ^ it will discard the pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably have a NaN in vector1 or vector2 components (NaN => not a number, can happen if there is a division by zero during vector1 or vector2 computations).

Please see this for a way to detect NaN:
[How to deal with NaN or inf in OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810158/how-to-deal-with-nan-or-inf-in-opengl-es-2-0-shaders)

So to solve the issue you need to look at how vector1 & vector2 are computed.

In order to confirm this is a NaN issue, use constant values for vector1/vector2 like:

```
// force values so we are sure dot will be 1.0
vector1 = vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0);
vector2 = vec3(1.0,1.0,0.0);

float brightness = dot(vector1, vector2);
brightness = max(brightness, 0.0);

// so this should never execute since dot is 1.0
if(brightness < -999) {
   discard;
}
```

It is totally impossible that the discard be executed with code above.
If you think this still happens, only other possible explanation would be that the code after the if test would be setting fragColor.rgb to black or  fragColor.a to zero causing no pixel to display if blending is enabled.

Comment: I thought that it could be NaN and I was actually trying to trace every change in these vectors. I am now going to give it a look again.

Comment: I found the mistake. You were right. The vector2 was NaN. I had accidently outputted that vector2 from vertex shader as vec4 and inputted it as vec3 in fragment shader. Thank you!